# Is it possible to use both Hibernate and Spring JDBC templates in a project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Currently I develop a project which was earlier supported by someone else and they used Hibernate. I want to use Spring JDBC template in this project because I'm unfamiliar with Hibernate.

Can one use both of them? Will be there conflicts if you use them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely normal and I saw the situation in one of my previous project though I think you should stick to the technology which is already used in the project unless you have a very good reason(performance, for example).

Comment: i am not good with hibernate , so can i use  spring JDBC template

Comment: @bharath yes, as I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will try to answer the questions you asked and one you should have asked.

> Can one use both of them?

Yes, it is common to use Hibernate for most persistence classes and JDBC for only some of them

> Will be there conflicts if you use them both?

No, provided you do not use both on same objects. If you did, you could easily get weird results due to cache inconsistencies

> Is *I am not good at Hibernate* a valid reason to use Spring JDBC template for next developments in a project based on Hibernate ?

IMHO **no** unless it is a decision from the head maintainer to change technology. For future maintainance sake, you should try to stick to previous usages, unless a clear documented decision says that from now on this will be the new usage. But that also means that whenever you change a class using the older technology, you **must** wonder whether it is time to port it to the new one.

TL/DR: If you are working on a real world serious project that will be used in production, you'd better learn Hibernate. It is a state of the art largely used framework and it is worth learning it. If you are working on a private project, you are on your own.

Comment: thank you for the valuable advises , i will learn it as soon as possible.due to the project dead line they agreed to use both. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do this. Sometimes for faster and better performance, people use JDBC template. If this is not the case, I will recommend you to use Hibernate as it is already implemented in the project.

For future study, please learn Spring Data JPA, it is very easy, need to configure your DB queries in an interface and Spring automatically creates an implementation of it.
Have a look –

[Spring Data JPA](http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa)